# Serilog / JSNLog .NET Core logging empty JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-core, serilog, jsnlog

I have a .NET Core project using Serilog and JSNLog for client side logging.  If I pass a JSON object from the client to the server and log it using Serilog, the logged JSON object is empty.

The ***very weird*** thing is that, if I have the debugger attached, the JSON is logged fine.

For example:

While debugging I get:

```
[11:00:01 FTL] this works
[11:00:02 INF] Request finished in 342.1967ms 200 text/plain
[11:00:02 FTL] "testMessage": "this is an error"
[11:00:02 INF] Request finished in 374.7837ms 200 text/plain
```

When Crtl+F5 I get:

```
[10:59:14 FTL] this works
[10:59:14 INF] Request finished in 253.3403ms 200 text/plain
[10:59:15 FTL] [[[]]]
[10:59:15 INF] Request finished in 267.2553ms 200 text/plain
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with Serilog or JSNLog, but any help would be appreciated.

I've made a very simple sample app to replicate this.  Using the default .NET Core Webapp

Dependencies are as shown:
[image: Dependencies]

in Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger();
        }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseJSNLog(new LoggingAdapter(loggerFactory));

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
}
```

And in my front end:

```
<script src="~/lib/jsnlog.js/jsnlog.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            JL().fatal({ testMessage: "this is an error" });
            JL().fatal("this works");
        </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. I took a look at JSNLog and what seemed to be the issue was the logging of the JSON .NET object that was being created when desearializing an object from the log message.

I did the following workaround:

1. I installed the Nuget package **Destructurama.JsonNet** (`Install-Package Destructurama.JsonNet`)
2. Then I changed the Logger configuration to include the destructuring:

   ```
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .Destructure.JsonNetTypes()
           .WriteTo.Console()
           .CreateLogger();
   ```
3. I then created a `CustomLoggingAdapter` class like this:

   ```
   public class CustomLoggingAdapter: ILoggingAdapter
   {
       private ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

       public CustomLoggingAdapter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
       {
           _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
       }

       public void Log(FinalLogData finalLogData)
       {
           ILogger logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger(finalLogData.FinalLogger);

           Object message = LogMessageHelpers.DeserializeIfPossible(finalLogData.FinalMessage);

           switch (finalLogData.FinalLevel)
           {
               case Level.TRACE: logger.LogTrace("{@logMessage}", message); break;
               case Level.DEBUG: logger.LogDebug("{@logMessage}", message); break;
               case Level.INFO: logger.LogInformation("{@logMessage}", message); break;
               case Level.WARN: logger.LogWarning("{@logMessage}", message); break;
               case Level.ERROR: logger.LogError("{@logMessage}", message); break;
               case Level.FATAL: logger.LogCritical("{@logMessage}", message); break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   and changed the log to have the following format `{@logMessage}`

Note: LogMessageHelpers.DeserializeIfPossible can be found in the JSONLog [GitHub](https://github.com/mperdeck/jsnlog/blob/master/jsnlog/Infrastructure/LogMessageHelpers.cs) repo

4. Then I changed the JSNLog configuration to take in my `CustomLoggingAdapter` like this:

   ```
    app.UseJSNLog(new CustomLoggingAdapter(loggerFactory), jsnlogConfiguration);
   ```

and the log messages appeared.

Let me know if that helps